# Remove session attributes which name starts from specific name

Tags: java, servlets, httpsession

In my servlet, if I want to remove a specific `session` attribute I run:

```
session.removeAttribute("user");
```

and I want to remove all of them:

```
session.invalidate();
```

How to remove only those session attributes which their name starts from a specific value? For example instead running:

```
session.removeAttribute("userDsdf");
session.removeAttribute("userSDFSF");
session.removeAttribute("userVSDfs");
session.removeAttribute("userESFDFS");
```

run something like `session.removeAttribute("user%");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through attribute names with stream:

```
Collections.list(session.getAttributeNames()).stream()
        .filter(a -> a.startsWith("user"))
            .forEach(a -> session.removeAttribute(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no method to do that work exactly, but you can do it yourself by enumerating attributes and filtering:

```
Enumeration<String> attributes = session.getAttributeNames();
while (attributes.hasMoreElements()) {
    String next = attributes.nextElement();
    if (!next.startsWith("user")) continue;
    session.removeAttribute(next);
}
```